# e4 Set ESelectionService Null

Tags: java, eclipse, e4

After my execute method I want to set the current selection `null`. I got this far but it won't work. After that, `selection` still holds the a value, which is not null.

```
    @Inject
    private ESelectionService selection;

    @Execute
    public void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) Foo foo, Shell shell) {
        if (true) {
           //do something!
           final Object NULL_OBJECT = new Object();
           selection.setSelection(NULL_OBJECT);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple selection services, one per context (`IEclipseContext`). You may be setting the selection in the wrong context.

Injecting the `ESelectionService` as a field of your class may mean you end up with the wrong service. Always inject this as a parameter of the `execute` method.

```
... no field injection

@Execute
public void execute(ESelectionService selection, @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) Foo foo, Shell shell) {
```